# overflow-x doesn't work on Safari after rotation

Tags: html, css, ipad, safari, touch

I am building a site where I need a certain div to be horizontal scrollable when overflown if the content is bigger than the screen. Okay, so this is easy - and it works on all browser but it doesnt work perfectly on Safari:

**Scenario:** Load page in potrait on iPad or iPhone. Content in the scrollable div is bigger than the screen. The scroll works fine. Now I rotate the screen to landscape and the content is now smaller than the screen and therefore there is no scrollbar. I rotate back to potrait, the scrollbar appears, but the scroll doesn't work. If I then refresh the page the scroll works again.

**Duplication of the issue:**
The scenario can be duplicated with this fiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/v7wvbupd/2/`. If you go to this fiddle with an Android product it works perfectly with each rotation. If you do the same with an Apple product you will encounter the bug.

The scroll - with rotations - works fine on all other mobile browsers than Safari.

I have been trying out several things from other posts and other sites but with no success.

**What I tried and didn't work:**

1. Setting the postion of body to relativ.
2. Adding the following: `html, body {overflow-x: hidden;}`.
3. Use: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;` on the scrollable div.
4. Adding `!important` to `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;` and `overflow-x: auto` to keep it from being overritten when rotatet.

I have also been looking into some js fixes like adding a timeout on the attribute but still with no results:

```
<script>
$("[scrollable]").css("-webkit-overflow-scrolling", "auto");
window.setTimeout(function () { $("[scrollable]").css("-webkit-overflow-scrolling", "touch") }, 100);
</script>
```

Most of the posts that I have come across are issues where the scroll doesn't work at all. In my situation it works until I rotate from landscape to potrait.

**My structure (simplified):**

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="header" class="col-md-12"></div>
  <div class="scrollableDiv">
  <div id="footer" class="col-md-12"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**My current CSS:**

```
html {
overflow-y: scroll;
height: 100%;
width:100%;
}

body {
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.scrollableDiv {
overflow-x: auto !important;
width: 800px;
overflow-y: hidden;
padding-bottom: 55px;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
}

.col-md-12{
width: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT**

My site is using Angularjs as a part of the solution. I just tested if wrapping it within some js was the problem but this had nothing to do with it either. It seems to be a common problem with the Safari only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this troubles with Safari by the past.
So simple things like overflow could become complicated ones.

I suggest you use iScroll.
Definetely the right solution for such a case.
http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5

Comment: This seems like a good solution. I will take a look at it and return with the results. Thank you.